# OpenJDK 7 Runtime Doesnt show up in my right click menu

Tags: lubuntu, minecraft

When I downloaded Cracked Minecraft onto my Linux Lubuntu 15.04, I wasn't able to right click it and open with "OpenJDK 7 Runtime Environment. I right clicked and did Properties and then Permissions then allowed Execute file to Anyone. Still can't. How can I do it? Please help ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .desktop file for Java:

1. Create a file called java.desktop
2. Open java.desktop in a text editor
3. Add this in your java.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Java
Exec=java -jar %f
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

4. Install that java.desktop file with the command `sudo desktop-file-install java.desktop`
   Now you can right-click on the .jar file and choose to open it with Java.

If I helped you, please upvote this answer and accept this answer.